# Intent vs Replace Fragment?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have an Arraylist named PersonList stored in Firebase FireStore. Every Person has a bunch of attributes (name, contact number, email, etc.).

I have RecyclerView displaying each person's name. That RecyclerView is stored in Fragment A. When I click on an Item in Recycler View, I use Fragment Manager to replace Fragment A with Fragment B. Fragment B lets me view all of that person's data (not just his name), plus maybe add or edit some data as well. Currently, I am able to get that person's name from Fragment A and pass it off as an argument and display it in Fragment B.

Now I plan to get the position of that Person Object onClick in Fragment A, call another instance of PersonList and use position to get all of a particular person's data (not just his name) displayed in Fragment B. I also want to be able to edit that data in Fragment B and have the changes reflected in my Firestore. My question is this: should I keep on replacing Fragment A with Fragment B? Or should I use intent instead? I am new to Java and AndroidStudio and am just feeling my way through, any other insights or opinions with my plan are welcome.

Comment: show A sample of your code where you stuck and what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> My question is this: should I keep on replacing Fragment A with Fragment B?

That's a way to go from one fragment to another. However, a more convenient way would be to use [navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) between fragments, which is a component of [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture).

If you understand Kotlin, here is a useful article where you can see how to interact with Firestore:

- [How to make a clean architecture Android app, using MVVM, Firestore, and Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8)

> Or should I use intent instead?

[Intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) are used for navigation between activities, not fragments.

Comment: Appreciate it my guy! Upvoted as well. Can I ask a follow up question? Please let me know if I should make a new post as well. 

Should I make a new instance of my firebase ArrayList in Fragment B or can I borrow the instance from Fragment A somehow? I've managed to pass the position of the Person in my RecyclerView, and I want to put this position in my Arraylist to get all of the person's data. Somehow I think this would be a very costly process.

Comment: Yes, you can pass any data from one fragment to another.